# How do I wrap a chained stateful computation in State monad?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, state-monad, continuation-passing

I have computations in this format: `s -> a -> s`, where `s` is the type of some state. The result of such a function is also the state of the next evaluation. For example,

```
appendInt :: String -> Int -> String
appendInt s i = s ++ (show i)
```

Then, `appendInt "Int: " 1` will give `"Int: 1"`, while `(appendInt $ appendInt "Int: 1") 2` will give `"Int: 12"`. However, I cannot find a way to put this kind of computation in a `State` Monad.

A first guess is `s -> (s,s)`, but then `a` cannot be passed in. Then, I tried `(a -> s) -> (s, a -> s)`, but again it is impossible to get `s` without `a`. `s -> (a,s)` won't work because `a` is the input instead of output.

How should I wrap this computation, then? Is the `State` monad appropriate for this?

Comment: BTW, I had this style working in Arrows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `State` just fine, or even better use `Writer`:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.State

appendInt :: Int -> Writer String ()
appendInt i = tell $ show i

appendInt' :: Int -> State String ()
appendInt' i = modify (++ show i)

main = do print . execWriter $ do
            tell "Int: "
            appendInt 1
            appendInt 2
          print . flip execState "Int: " $ do
            appendInt' 1
            appendInt' 2
```

Comment: I mean `a`. But then I get confused about when I should use the state `s`. Do I use `s -> (a,s)` and `runState` when I don't want to expose the state, but instead want to "transform" that to another format?

Comment: @CarlDong `runState` turns the monadic action into a function. `state` turns a function into a monadic action. They're basically converters, they don't any magic.

Comment: @CarlDong: There are basically three variants, `runState`, `evalState` and `execState`. You use `runState` when you want to extract both the value contained in the monad, and the monadic context (the state). You use `evalState` when you want only the value, and `execState` when you want only the context. In all cases, they don't give you the output directly, but give you a function that takes an initial context (the `s`) to the desired output. That's why I supply `"Int: "` to `execState`, it's the initial context.

Comment: @CarlDong: Additionally, since we're not using the `a`, this basically means we're not doing a monadic computation (subsequent computations are not performed differently based on the output of earlier computations). So instead of using `do` notation we could have written `flip execState "Int: " $ appendInt' 1 *> appendInt'2`, relying on the `Applicative` instance of `State`, rather than the `Monad` instance.

Comment: Apparently `>>` also works. Thank you for the explanation, I did not notice `execState` and `evalState` before

Comment: @CarlDong: Yes `>>` is basically the monadic equivalent of `*>`. Since all `Monad`s are `Applicative`s but not vice versa, you gain some generality by using `*>`, and in some cases using `Applicative` code can result in a performance gain as well.

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is possible, for example like this:

```
appendIntM :: MonadState String m => Int -> m ()
appendIntM i = modify $ flip appendInt i
```

Had you made the order of arguments more "conventional", it would just be a composition with `modify`.

[<kbd>Live On Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/de3d86ab5d0e27bb)